# Posting on user wall doesn't work if link is included

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post to a user wall using the Graph API. I tested using my own wall, and I have authenticated my Facebook app to `publish_stream`.

```
post_params = {
  access_token:FACEBOOK_APP_TOKEN,
  link:'http://example.com',
  picture:"http://example.com/images/logo.png",
  message:"dummy",
  description:'dummy'
}

get_facebook_client().client.post("#{user_fb_id}/feed", post_params)
```

I can successfully post something to my wall if I don't have the `link` parameter (containing our company url). If I include the link param, Facebook would still return the ID of the status update like `{"id": "4804827_871793267189"}`, like a successful post request, but post won't appear on my wall.

The above use the ruby gem `rest-more`, but this behavior happens when I hand code everything too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that I can post any other link (even other subdomain my company url).

So I think Facebook will ignore posting with a link which the user have shared before.

Answer (score 0):

umm from looking at your code, if you add a comma at the end of link, wouldn't that fix the issue ?

Comment: My bad, I was probably copying from console and left this comma out. But I think this is not the core issue